# How to Use rater js to Display rate of user in Jquery each function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am using [raterJs](https://auxiliary.github.io/rater/) to rate and display rate of users in Jquery.
This is i am trying  **jquery**

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: api_url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        var userlist = data.response;
            var markup = '';
            $.each(userlist, function(key, value) {
                var options = {
                    max_value: 5,
                    step_size: 0.5,
                    initial_value: value.rating,
                }
                markup += '<li id="' + value.user_id + '" class="collection-item user_rating avatar">' +
                    '<img src="' + api_url + 'backend/web/uploads/' + value.image + '" alt="userimage" class="circle"></img>' +
                    '<span class="title">' + value.name + '</span><br>' + '<div class="rating"></div>' +
                    '<a id="' + value.user_id + '" data-val="' + value.user_id + '" class="book_button book_button_id waves-effect waves-light btn-small secondary-content" value="' + value.user_id + '">Book Now</a>' +
                    '</li>';
                $(".rating").rate(options);
            });
            $('#user_list').append(markup);

           
    }
});
```

**ajax response**

```
"response":[{"user_id":"717","skill_id":"34","name":"ddgfgd","image":null,"content":"good","rating":"5"},
{"user_id":"745","skill_id":"34","name":"gfgdd","image":null,"content":null,"rating":"5"},
{"user_id":"710","skill_id":"34","name":"kichuzzz","image":null,"content":"","rating":"4.5"},
{"user_id":"771","skill_id":"34","name":"neenu","image":null,"content":"neenu's updated review","rating":"3.5"},
```

**html**

```
 <ul class="collection list_skills" id="user_list">
 </ul>
```

This is not working and even didn't display rating stars , and i got a answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316098/div-class-not-working-inside-jquery-but-works-outside) .
so, i called the  $(".rating").rate(); after $('#user_list').append(markup); and it's working,But i cant set the parameters to the rate function as variable **option** cause the rating is in value.rating in $each(function()).
How to pass the rating to the rate() function
NB:- response is json_ecnoded array that return from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to append your content inside `ul` tag then use `$("#user_list li:last .rating").rate({//your option})` to initialize your rater plugin with rating value.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = {
  "response": [{
      "user_id": "717",
      "skill_id": "34",
      "name": "ddgfgd",
      "image": null,
      "content": "good",
      "rating": "2.5"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "745",
      "skill_id": "34",
      "name": "gfgdd",
      "image": null,
      "content": null,
      "rating": "5"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "710",
      "skill_id": "34",
      "name": "kichuzzz",
      "image": null,
      "content": "",
      "rating": "4.5"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "771",
      "skill_id": "34",
      "name": "neenu",
      "image": null,
      "content": "neenu's updated review",
      "rating": "3.5"
    }
  ]
}

/*$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: api_url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {*/

var userlist = data.response;

$.each(userlist, function(key, value) {
  //append it 
  $('#user_list').append('<li id="' + value.user_id + '" class="collection-item user_rating avatar">' +
    '<img src="backend/web/uploads/' + value.image + '" alt="userimage" class="circle"></img>' +
    '<span class="title">' + value.name + '</span><br>' + '<div class="rating"></div>' +
    '<a id="' + value.user_id + '" data-val="' + value.user_id + '" class="book_button book_button_id waves-effect waves-light btn-small secondary-content" value="' + value.user_id + '">Book Now</a>' +
    '</li>');
  //then find last li appended -> rating intialize it
  $("#user_list li:last .rating").rate({
    max_value: 5,
    step_size: 0.5,
    initial_value: value.rating,
  });
});



/*}
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rater-jquery@1.0.0/rater.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collection list_skills" id="user_list">
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for $("#user_list li:last .rating") this is amazing and reduce my block of code